# What will the actual source code this template creates look like?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};


const int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
const int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
```

After pre-compilation, if we could magically see what the compiler produced, would we actually see:

```
const int x = 24;
const int y = 1;
```

And would we see actual definitions for the `struct Factorial`, multiple of these? If so how would they look? I'm trying wrap my head around this part of the metaprogramming process.

Comment: `Factorial<901>::value` crashed my DEV-C++: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `g++ -fdump-tree-original` on this code, I see the following result, which for this case seems to confirm your suspicion:

```
;; Function int main() (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original



{
  const int x = 24;
  const int y = 1;

  <<cleanup_point   const int x = 24;>>;
  <<cleanup_point   const int y = 1;>>;
}
return <retval> = 0;
```

Comment: Interesting, and there is no code generated for the `struct Factorial` at all?

Comment: Why does `y` get cleaned up after `x`? Shouldn't destruction order be reversed?

Comment: @Fellowshee, what code do you expect to be generated? There are no static variables in it which need space, nor are there functions which need code, nor are there any instances of the struct ever built. All the compiler need do is evaluate which enum value is being referred to, which it can easily do at compile time.

Before this phase, an expansion takes place which logically creates definitions for Factorial<24> down to Factorial<0>, but these do not generate any code and aren't needed any further.

Comment: @JeremyRoman interesting, thanks. Suppose I had instantiated the template twice, as in `Factorial<3> foo; Factorial<4> bar;` -- these are both of class name `Factorial` so there would be two different definitions created, since their `enum` constant would be different? How would these definitions be named in the pre-compiled source?

Comment: Generally, only one template instantiation per compilation unit is generated. However, unlike #include and #define (which operate in the preprocessor), template expansion occurs as part of the C++ compiler, and there isn't any need to be able to generate what you call "pre-compiled source code" from them.